# Who was Dr. Miranda Bailey's favourite resident on Grey's Anatomy?

Tags: greys-anatomy

On the show Grey's Anatomy, was it ever said who was Dr. Bailey's favourite resident from her residents?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange! There is nothing wrong with the general premise of your Q, but it is very short in length and as it's currently worded, seems a bit opinion-based. Feel free to make edits so as to avoid your question getting closed or deleted. The following link is to the site's help center, to help get you started: https://movies.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: It's short, but I don't see how this is opinion-based. If it was ever stated in the show who Dr. Bailey's favourite resident is, then that's the answer. If it's never stated, then the answer is "we don't know".

Comment: @F1Krazy I generally agree, but it was not made clear she was looking for a strong source... "was it ever said"....well, said by whom? I didn't vote to close, because I believed there was a good answer, but was trying to make the Q stronger by prompting a little more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Grey's Anatomy fandom wiki](https://greysanatomy.fandom.com/wiki/Miranda_Bailey), George O'Malley was Miranda Bailey's favorite.

> Bailey said George was her favorite of her interns. She also named her son after him. He coached her through her labor and delivery, allowing her to work through the stress of her husband's car accident.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Great point! I removed it. You can remove your comment now, so _that_ doesn't spoil it.